# ng update from 7 to 8 doesn't update the code

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to update from angular 7 to 8. Here is what I did. First I ran `yarn upgrade --latest`. I noticed that this will give me typescript 3.6.3, which is too new for angular, so I downgraded it to 3.5.3. Now when I try to run my app I get a lot of errors (like @ViewChild missing an argument)

So, I thought, this can be fixed with `ng update -all`:

```
$> ng update --all
Using package manager: 'yarn'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 66 dependencies.
              Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.4 <3.6", would install "3.6.3").
Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
```

It wants to update `typescript` to 3.6.3. Now when I run this command with `--force` it indeed only updates typescript. So it seems that: `ng update --all === yarn upgrade --latest`.

The question I have is can `ng update` also fix my code, I got that impression, but I don't see that magic.

Comment: No, that command absolutely does not update your code automatically, it only updates dependencies. You are responsible for updating the code.

Comment: you can use `--force` and then `--migrate-only` _after_ the automatic code update for `ViewChild` fails. That's what I did. @AlexanderStaroselsky that's false. ng update attempts to update code to migrate the use of certain APIs. This is documented.

Comment: You might want to follow the [official migration guide](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: Actually, the migration 7-8 guide says that it will update ViewChild queries for you... `ng update will update your [ViewChild] queries automatically, but it will err on the side of making your queries static for compatibility. ` But it does not.